# convert Zulu time to +8GMT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

So I am using Mongodb to store datetime in an array.

`2021-01-16T05:00:00.000Z`
I am wanting to convert that to +8GMT time in my reactJS app.

I am wondering if there is any easy way to do this?

I tried this

```
function Dateformat(props){
    var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    return new Date(props.timestamp).toLocaleDateString([],options);
}
```

but I just get it prints the same time and date that is in the database

Comment: *FYI:* The `Z` at the end means it's Zulu time, aka **UTC** time, not PST time.

Comment: Here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Do you want **always** UTC+8 hours (i.e. regardless if summer or winter)? Or do you need to consider daylight saving times?

Answer (score 0):

*Edited answer*

You can use the [`toLocaleString` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) under the Date Object.

```
const TimeDisplayComponent = (props) => {

  const convertedTime = new Date(props.theTimeYouwantToConvert).toLocaleString( 'sv', { timeZoneName: 'short' } );

  return <div>{convertedTime}</div>;
}
```

*End of edited answer*

---

The date you gave is an [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. To change it to GMT+8, you  can do

```
const now = new Date();
const output = new Date(
  now.getTime() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60_000)
);
```

---

Alternatively, you could always use a Date Time library like [LuxonJS](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [DateFNS](https://date-fns.org/). It is often easier to handle time conversion with a library since there are too many problems associated with date-time manipulation in code (leap years, daylight savings, etc).

Comment: Sorry I kinda understand but where do I put the ``` props.timestamp ```` part because I get that now is the time now - and the output but don't you need to set the now to the props.timestamp for this to work?

Comment: Is your input a timestamp? Because that makes things so much easier as compared to ISO-8601

Comment: Mongodb stores it like 2021-01-16T05:00:00.000Z

That is what I need to convert.

Comment: I just found an easier solution, you can use the [toLocaleString API](new Date(`2021-01-16T05:00:00.000Z`).toLocaleString( 'sv', { timeZoneName: 'short' } );), I've updated the solution